# Writing a bash script to run a server

Tags: bash

This is how I launch the server in the terminal:

`~$ cd meteor/writer10 && meteor`

I have to do that every time I start Ubuntu so I thought it would be nice to write a bash script so automate that.

What's the best way to do it?

Comment: The recommended way to start/stop server processes is by using Upstart (see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/). However, that takes quite a bit of studying.

Comment: So the current working directory doesn't matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write a simple upstart script. Run `sudoedit /etc/init/meteor.conf` and copy in something like (see notes after) this:

```
description "Meteor"

start on filesystem and network-up
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn

setuid user
setgid user

chdir /home/user/meteor/writer10/
exec /path/to/meteor
```

That needs a couple of edits to fix the paths (that I don't know). Replace all instances of `user` with your username (run `echo $USER` if you're not sure) and the path to the `meteor` binary (run `which meteor`) needs fixing in.

If you don't want to reboot, you can run `sudo start meteor` to bring it up immediately but otherwise it should start it when the network comes up and keep running.